# Receiving trackball events with an Android NativeActivity

Tags: android, events, trackball, native-activity

I have a NativeActivity-based application that wants to receive trackball events.

According to the (sketchy) documentation, I should be receiving these via the `struct android_app`'s `onInputEvent()` callback, the same as I do for key and motion events. However, I'm not getting any. Looking at the tracing the event gets sent to the glue layer but is apparently consumed by the call to `AInputQueue_preDispatchEvent()` in `process_input()`, and so never gets delivered to my application.

Has anyone gotten trackball events working with NativeActivity, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

you can override onKeyDown() and use KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN,KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT,KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT,KEYCODE_DPAD_UP to handle all event . I was using it for a game on HTC desire device.

Comment: Sorry, last comment posted while rushed: plus, I want to get at the trackball events before they get converted to dpad events, because I need the analogue control.